# Code examples for python do not formate on stackoverflow for me

Tags: python

I tried to post code examples of Python3 and it was a mess.

[image]

Here is what I get when I try using the code tags.

Comment: Paste your code, mark it, then type Ctl-k or use the `{}` tool.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting for code formatting help.

Comment: And questions about using SO belong in meta.stackoverflow.com, not in SO itself.

Comment: ACVAK : open your file, CTRL+A   and CTRL+C, then edit your post, CTR+V, --> CTRL+A  --> CTRL+K

Answer (score 0):

I found I had to go back and re-select the code after inserting it and then the CTL-k featured worked.

I had to select all but the first line (which had the proper indentation), then I used the CTL-K on the selected lines and with the indentation correct the code looked correct.

Worked way different from the wiki mark up to which I was mentally referring.